# Cannot get running total even with unique Id's

Tags: sql, oracle

-- Below is my query & I would like the 2 expense codes to be grouped together 
-- I have tried analytical functions and got the same result

```
WITH t AS
  (SELECT quote_section_id,
    expense_id,
    Quoted Quoted,
    NULL procured
  FROM VW_PM_SUM_Quoted
  WHERE VW_PM_SUM_Quoted.QUote_section_id = '1000065052'
  UNION
  SELECT quote_section_id ,
    expense_id ,
    NULL Quoted ,
    procured
  FROM VW_PM_SUM_procured
  WHERE VW_PM_SUM_procured.QUote_section_id = '1000065052'
  )
select quote_section_id, expense_id, quoted, procured
from t
```

-- result

```
Quote_section_id expense_id quoted procured 
1000065052      1000000547   10320
1000065052      1000000547           825.9
1000065052      1000000571     546  
1000065052      1000000582          2201.43
1000065052      1000000619  102297
```

-- Desired result

```
Quote_section_id expense_id quoted  procured balance 
1000065052      1000000547   10320  825.9    9494.1     
1000065052      1000000571     546            546
1000065052      1000000582          2201.43  -2201.43
1000065052      1000000619  102297           102297
```

Comment: Can you please better format your code and your data? The result you posted is what you already can get or your desired output?

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do and what data you are starting with.

Comment: Sorry - The result is what I get -

Comment: Sorry - The result is what I get 
I would like the result to group the expense_ID’s like below 
Quote_section_id     Expense_id          quoted       procured  Balance 
1000065052            1000000547             10320        825.9           9494.10       
1000065052            1000000571              546                                546
1000065052           1000000582                                2201.43       -2201.43
1000065052           1000000619              102297                          102297

Comment: A running total usually shows a series of data ordered by something.I see no ORDER BY in your query. Are you really looking for a running total?

Comment: @user3602012 . . . Edit your question and put the desired results *in the question*.

Comment: Order by gives same result

Comment: Please edit your question and include the data which is input to this process; that is, the data which is in your tables `VW_PM_SUM_Quoted` and `VW_PM_SUM_procured` which your SQL statement is supposed to process. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are simply looking for a join. A full outer join in this case, where either one or both tables have data for an expense ID.

```
select 
  quote_section_id,
  expense_id,
  q.quoted,
  p.procured,
  nvl(q.quoted, 0) - nvl(p.procured, 0) as balance
from vw_pm_sum_quoted q
full outer join vw_pm_sum_procured p using (quote_section_id, expense_id)
where quote_section_id = '1000065052'
order by quote_section_id, expense_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that what you are looking for is

```
WITH t AS
  (SELECT quote_section_id,
    expense_id,
    Quoted Quoted,
    NULL procured
  FROM VW_PM_SUM_Quoted
  WHERE VW_PM_SUM_Quoted.QUote_section_id = '1000065052'
  UNION
  SELECT quote_section_id ,
    expense_id ,
    NULL Quoted ,
    procured
  FROM VW_PM_SUM_procured
  WHERE VW_PM_SUM_procured.QUote_section_id = '1000065052'
  )
select quote_section_id, expense_id, Sum(quoted), sum(procured), sum(nvl(quoted,0) - nvl(procured,0)) balance
from t
group by quote_section_id, expense_id
```

Comment: Thanks but the balance did not work - Below one worked

Comment: The NVLs were missing I guess... maybe you can try again

Comment: Hi @user3602012, Maybe you can try again, I've corrected the balance column